# Registration and login php code

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am writing a registration and log in program using php and mysql. The registration part is working just fine but when i try to log in with the valid credentials as per per deatils stored upon registration i am still getting invalid regnumber and password. here is the code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
 header("Location: studentportal.html");
 exit;
 }

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

 $Regnumber = strip_tags($_POST['Regnumber']);
 $Password = strip_tags($_POST['Password']);

 $Regnumber = $DBcon->real_escape_string($Regnumber);
 $Password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($Password);

  $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT Sessionid, Regnumber, Password FROM      regstudents WHERE Regnumber='$Regnumber'");
  $row=$query->fetch_array();

  $count = $query->num_rows; // if email/password are correct returns          must be 1 row

 if (password_verify($Password, $row['Password']) && $count==1) {
 $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['Sessionid'];
header("Location: home.php");
 } else {
 $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid     Regnumber or Password !
</div>";
  }
 $DBcon->close();
 }
?>
```

Comment: Make sure $Password and $row['Password'] have valid values. Make sure value of $Regnumber is really in database. Do checks for those.

Comment: Also do - echo `$DBcon->error` check after your `query()` so you know if there's an error and what error it is.